# How do I change the rules in Firebase so each user have their own list of todos?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm new to programming and firebase, I created a todo app with react native and successfully connected firebase to store the todos, now I added authentication so I can create my profile to store my todos in my account. When I enter with a different email I still can see the same list I created with the previous account.

this is the firebase rule I want to modify:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 10, 29);
    }
  }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

I tried to add this as suggested in another page but it breaks my app

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the List.tsx component**

```
const List = ({ navigation }: RouterProps) => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const todoRef = collection(FIRESTORE_DB, 'todos');
        const subscriber = onSnapshot(todoRef, {
            next: (snapshot) => {
                const todos: Todo[]= [];
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    console.log(doc.data());
                    todos.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        ...doc.data(),
                    } as Todo);
                });
                setTodos(todos);
            },
        })
        return () => subscriber();
    }, []);
    
    const addTodo = async () => {
        const doc =  await addDoc(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, 'todos'), { title: todo, done: false});
        setTodo('');
    }

    const renderTodo = ({ item }: any) => {
        const ref = doc(FIRESTORE_DB, `todos/${item.id}`);

        const toggleDone = async() => {
            updateDoc(ref, { done: !item.done })
        }

        const deleteTask = async() => {
            deleteDoc(ref);
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.todoContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleDone} style={styles.todo}>
                    {item.done && <Ionicons name='md-checkmark-circle' size={30} color='green' />}
                    {!item.done && <Entypo name='circle' size={30} color='black' />}
                    <Text style={styles.todoText}>{item.title}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Ionicons name='trash-bin-outline' size={30} color='red' onPress={deleteTask} />
            </View>
        )
    }

  return (.......rendering part)
}
```

**And this is the Login.tsx component**

```
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from '../../firebaseConfig';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from 'firebase/auth';

function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const auth = FIREBASE_AUTH;

  const signIn = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log('RESPONSE:', response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const signUp = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log('RESPONSE:', response);
      alert('Welcome onboard!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (......rendering part)
}
```

[image: click for screenshot of what I see in the firestore database]

not so sure what to do as I mentioned before I'm new to programming in general and firebase, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Firestore the data model always starts with a collection, then documents under that, and then under each document you can have further subcollections - each of which then again has documents.

At least one problem in your rules is the path you build here:

```
match /todos/{userId}/{document=**} {
```

This path consists of three parts: `todo`, `{userId}`, and then `{document=**}`, which means that is doesn't seem to follow the pattern I outlined above.

You'll want to keep the alternating of collection and documents, so for example with:

```
match /users/{userId}/todos/{document} {
```

---

Based on the code you provided in the update:

```
const addTodo = async () => {
    const doc =  await addDoc(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, 'todos'), { title: todo, done: false});
    setTodo('');
}
```

This code tries to add a document to the `todos` collection, but your security rules say that a user can only add documents under **their own UID** - and your code doesn't do that.

If you look at the rules I added above in this answer, they'd match code that looks like this:

```
const addTodo = async () => {
  if (getAuth().currentUser) {
    const uid = getAuth().currentUser.uid;
    const userTodoCollection = collection(FIRESTORE_DB, 'users', uid, 'todos');
    const doc =  await addDoc(userTodoCollection, { title: todo, done: false});
    setTodo('');
  }
  else {
    console.error("No user is signed in, so we can't add a note");
  }
}
```

Comment: I entered this now and got a similar error in my app:


rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/todos/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}

got this error:

@firebase/firestore:, Firestore (10.4.0): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:, FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: also maybe this can help: in the firestore page of my app the structure is:  (collection column) todos > (todos column) "id of the todo" > (id of todo column) done: false, title: "test"

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal repro, which includes both rules and code. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Writing a good minimal repro](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: thank you for the advice Frank, I provided more context now.

Comment: I added an update to my answer based on that. Note that we're reaching the end of what we can reasonably do in a Q&A format here with that though.